# Crystal Reports not creating new page after

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Reports XI and have a pretty basic report.  It is formatted like this:
Report Header
Page Header
Group Header #1
Details
Group Footer #1
Report Footer
Page Footer

My issue is that the Details area is pulling records from a database and depending there can be enough records associated with the Group Header #1 that the report will span multiple pages.  This appears to work except that the report after (this is a mass mailer type of a report for individuals) does not start on a new page, causing print issues.

The Report Footer and Page Footer both have New Page After turned on (they are grayed out and I cannot alter them.  The Details (in the Section Expert) has Free-Form Placement and Keep Together turned on only.

Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean "...the report after does not start on a new page." Do you mean the _group_ after?

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn on the group header new page before with a formula to skip the first group.

1. Right click the "group header #1"
2. Click "section expert"
3. Click "new page before" formula workshp button (on the right of the checkbox)
4. Write the formula

   groupnumber > 1

This will put each group in a separate page. The formula is important to avoid a blank initial page.